# Porque me muestra la referencia en memoria a pesar que ya lo pase a lista

Tags: python, array, zip, itertools

Debo imprimir todas las funciones inyectivas posibles que pueden existir dado un dominio y un contradominio (dos listas) finitas y ya definidas.

Por ejemplo tengo lo siguiente:

> Dominio = [a,b]
>
> Contradominio = [c,d,e]

Sé que pueden existen 6 funciones inyectivas, pero no sé cómo mostrarlas. He hecho lo siguiente:

```
print("Las posibles funciones inyectivas son:\n")
        inyectivas = [zip(Dominio,Contradominio) for elemento in itertools.permutations(Contradominio)]
        Inyectivas = list(inyectivas)
        print(Inyectivas)
```

La variable inyectiva, según Python es un *Generator*, por ello es que después lo pase a una lista, sin embargo, cuando trato de imprimir, ya sea de esa forma o con un ciclo For obtengo lo siguiente:

> <zip object at 0x00000192E697BD00>

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no me aparezca eso, sino el valor al que se refiere?

Comment: Convierte el zip interno en una lista `inyectivas = [list(zip(Dominio,Contradominio)) ...]`. Si haces eso puedes directamente usar `print(inyectivas)` ahorrándote la línea `Inyectivas = list(inyectivas)`.

Comment: eso hice! y sirvio! jaja mil gracias!